# TypeError: $.event.props is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um slider como este de exemplo: http://themes.audemedia.com/html/servereast/vps-slider-6-plans.html

No meu caso ele esta apresentando o seguinte erro no console quando clico no botão para deslizar/arrastar:

```
TypeError: $.event.props is undefined[Learn More] jquery.ui.widget.js:20:361
_trigger http://localhost/2018/js/jquery.ui.widget.js:20:361
_start http://localhost/2018/js/jquery.ui.slider.js:58:8
_mouseCapture http://localhost/2018/js/jquery.ui.slider.js:45:9
_mouseDown http://localhost/2018/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js:4:275
_mouseInit/< http://localhost/2018/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js:2:59
dispatch http://localhost/2018/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:1626:181
add/q.handle http://localhost/2018/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:1588:86
```

HTML: https://pastebin.com/0gm4ccSv

**jquery.ui.widget.js**: https://pastebin.com/EiUMK6Bt
**jquery.ui.mouse.js**: https://pastebin.com/ijakmNyV
**jquery.ui.slider.js**: https://pastebin.com/TRxGqmg6
**pagina.js**: https://pastebin.com/jEMvUAPP

Alguma dica do que pode esta ocorrendo?

Comment: Ele esta sendo carregado sim, esqueci de colocar no pastebin. Conforme pode ver no log do console: http://localhost/2018/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme informa **[esta página no site oficial](http://jQuery.event.props%20and%20jQuery.event.fixHooks%20removed)**, a propriedade `jQuery.event.props` foi removida desde a versão 3.0.0 do jQuery:

**Breaking change: jQuery.event.props and jQuery.event.fixHooks removed**

> jQuery's event handling performance increased thanks to a
>   reorganization of event property management. The main improvement is
>   that jQuery now only calculates or copies a property on the first
>   access, rather than calculating and copying them up front. This is a
>   really big win with properties that may force layout that the event
>   handler may not even need. The most common use we know of was to add
>   properties for pointer events, which is no longer necessary because
>   those events are supported already in jQuery 3.0. The jQuery Migrate
>   plugin provides support for these properties if you still need them.

Então você tem 2 alternativas:

1. Usar um plugin adicional chamado **[jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate)**, que dá suporte à propriedade ou,
2. Usar uma versão anterior à 3.0.0 do jQuery.

> **Obs.:** a página que você mencionou usa jQuery v2.1.4, que pode ser conferida **[neste link](http://themes.audemedia.com/html/servereast/js/jquery.min.js)**.

Fonte: **[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682004/jquery-event-props-is-undefined)**

Comment: Muito bom, você sabe alguma alternativa para a propriedade `$ .browser`? No jQuery Migrate não há suporte também..

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/14431233/1377664

Comment: Pois é, cheguei a usar o `$.support`, mas ficou lento para deslizar, bem estranho.. Obrigado =)

Comment: Será que usando uma versão jQuery 2.9 não seria uma boa solução? Não é tão antiga assim.

Comment: O problema que o jquery migrate vai só até a versão 3.0.1, e eu preciso que a versão 3.1.1 seja carregada..